# Alignment of elements on a web page

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a making a menu on a webpage and can't seem to get the elements to line up correctly. I have two buttons and two drop down menus, image attached below.

[image]

What sort of CSS styling can I do that will make the drop-down menus align horizontally with the 'Go' buttons? I tried adjusting the bottom and top margins of both elements but that doesn't seem to be what I am looking for.

Here is the current CSS for both elements:

```
select.small {   //<- drop downs
    width: 120px; 
    margin-bottom: 0px; 
}

button.small{  //<- buttons
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Any input would be appreciated as I am fairly new at this.

Comment: can you post it to a www.jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `position` of the buttons to `relative` and add:

```
top: 5px;
```

or whatever is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should try `vertical-align: middle;` first, but it depends on your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use table with no border and store these elements in table data. Also use padding style in it to make it look cozy.